# Bots cannot crawl old parts of site with "Disallow: /old/" and "Disallow: /old"?

Tags: robots.txt

Correct me if I am wrong, this means bots cannot crawl the old parts of the site?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /old/
Disallow: /old
```

Since it has been days that I have not received any traffic and found out about the robot.txt setup.

Comment: Aside: Since robots.txt is _prefix matching_, the first `Disallow` directive above (with a slash) is superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

This does not meant "old" as in "advanced age", it means /old as in directory/URL. For example, www.example.com`/old`/how-to-bake-special-brownies.html.

I assume /old is not your entire site, however if it is, then that would explain things.

Comment: since the site went to full revamped and design so I was assuming that the new robot txt setup prevented the crawlers from accessing the old directories/URL

Comment: @TonyLogarta The code you provided looks fine. Whenever you change a site, there is a disruption in search for a while as the search engine goes through your site and re-evaluates it. Each new page has to prove itself with performance metrics too. So it takes a while.